# How to do Group Concat in System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I am trying to concatenate strings in Dynamic linq, i.e. smth like `string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.item1))` in regular linq

my dynamic linq looks something like this

```
result.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().GroupBy("new {it.id.ToString() as entity_id, it[\"item2\"] as item2}", "it").Select("new{key.entity_id, key.item2,
String.Join(\", \", it.Select(it[\"item1\"].ToString())) as item1}")
```

but it obviously doesn't work, any ideas
I just want a comma separated string for each of the groups

**Edit Added examples of data:**

just to illustrate the data problem
How it looks like:

[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkeZF.png)

Note: item1 repeats twice for PK 1 because it comes from a N:N relationship,i need to Group Concat it on say pk

[Required State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSILT.png)

**RESOLVED**

I have found a way to resolve this issue, in my case i needed to add more functionality to System.Linq.Dynamic, as per [How to implement SelectMany in System.Linq.Dynamic ExpressionParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269475/how-to-implement-selectmany-in-system-linq-dynamic-expressionparser) by pil0t
**As per the answer you need to change**

1)  the signatures interface **IEnumerableSignatures**
and add to it:

`void Select(string selector);
    void SelectMany(string selector);/*not needed for this but good to have*/`

2) modify **ParseAggregate** function as per his/her answer to add

`....
    if (signature.Name == "Min" || signature.Name == "Max")
    {
       typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType, args[0].Type };
    }
    else if (signature.Name == "Select")
    {
       typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType, Expression.Lambda(args[0],innerIt).Body.Type};
    }
    else if (signature.Name == "SelectMany")
    {
       var type = Expression.Lambda(args[0], innerIt).Body.Type;
       var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces().Union(new[] { type });
       Type resultType = interfaces.Single(a => a.Name == typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name).GetGenericArguments()[0];
       typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType, resultType };
    }
    ....`

3) recompile add to project

4) Use as follows: String.Join(\", \", Select(it[\"item1\"].ToString())

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [*System.Linq.Dynamic*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) you can concat in your *Select new* this way

```
Select("new(name,courseID, (name + courseID.ToString()) as y)")
```

Below you have a complete console application so you can test the entire code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<course> Courses = new List<course>();
            Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CA", courseID = 1 });
            Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CB", courseID = 2 });
            Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CC", courseID = 3 });

            string column_name = "name";
            string column_value = "C";
            string where = string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", column_name); 
            var result = Courses.Where(where, column_value).Select("new(name,courseID, (name + courseID.ToString()) as y)").Take(50);   
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class course
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int courseID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for a response, but im searching for a **group** concat, i added examples of data above